# Postgresql-Check if today is outside Array of Dates

Tags: postgresql

I am beginner with Postgres.
I want to select the rows where Today is greater than an Array of Dates that I have stored.

This is what i wrote which does not work (error)

```
    SELECT
    bool_or(now()::date @> a_date) AS some_of_the_dates_lies_within_range
FROM
(SELECT unnest(dateofdeparture) AS a_date from alerts) as S0;
```

This is how my row is

```
SELECT unnest(dateofdeparture) AS a_date from alerts

a_date
2019-01-12
2019-01-13
2019-01-14
2019-01-15
2019-01-16
2019-01-17
2019-01-18
```

Any pointers help would be much appreciated.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are probably looking for the `ANY` or `ALL` operator on the `ARRAY` type

Assuming that `dateofdeparture` is a `DATE[]` array , what you need is either

```
select * from alerts WHERE current_date > ANY (dateofdeparture);
```

OR

```
select * from alerts WHERE current_date > ALL (dateofdeparture);
```

[**Demo**](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=postgres_10&fiddle=d3cfe7cdca0087ab04e58aaf937ec79f)

Comment: Are you sure it is not `> ALL` that is asked for?

Comment: That helped. So I am trying to filter all rows which are passed current date and this hopefully nailed it. select * from alerts WHERE NOT current_date < ANY (dateofdeparture);

Comment: @SouravChatterjee : So, `ANY` gave you the result you're expecting?